# VLOOKUP error in Excel #NA

Tags: excel, vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP(A5,'vlookup HT'!$A$2:$B$978,2,0)
```

When I use this above vlookup it works correctly but when there is no data available it shows up as #NA.

Is there a way to get it to show a 0 instead of #NA?  I am working with numbers and need to do totals and am unable to. The workaround I have for now is to copy and do a paste special in another worksheet and then replace the #NA with 0.

Answer (score 2):

This will let you difince addiional errors in addition to #na:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A5,'vlookup HT'!$A$2:$B$978,2,0), 0)
```

Comment: IFNA is only going to work if the user has Excel 2013. Also, the only other error I can think of that would be raised here is the #REF and that would just signal to rebuild the formula.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,'vlookup HT'!$A$2:$B$978,2,0), 0)
```